# using conditionals on enqueue styles

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, conditional-tags, wp-enqueue-style

I want to run my css code on a specific page in admin area. What is the best approach please?

A:

```
function register_style() {
    if (is_page..something) {
        wp_enqueue_style('style', PLUGIN_URL . 'style.css');
    }
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'register_style');
```

B:

```
function register_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style('style', PLUGIN_URL . 'style.css');
}

if (is_page..something) {
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'register_style');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for A) (but give that function another name to avoid collisions), because you can be absolutely sure that all manipulation of the request is over once `admin_enqueue_scripts` is fired. You cannot be sure if you just put it into the functions.php (or where ever this code will live).

I don't really see a (non-edge-case where somebody is doing something strange) scenario where B) will get you in trouble, but A) is much cleaner imho. A) might (theoretically; humans won't notice until we evolve quite a bit or you go back down to ancient CPUs) a tiny bit heavier since both the conditional and the action have to be run if the conditional returns false.